# Show a message about the expiration of the timer in the background of the application and when using it android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, countdowntimer

There is a task: the application has a `CountDownTimer`. I need to make sure that the user sees a message (for example, it could be `Toast` messsage) when the timer expires. The timer depends on real time, so even if the user does not use the application, the timer still runs. However, there is a condition - if the timer ended exactly when the user was on the `fragment`, then this message is shown to him. If the user has entered the application after the timer has expired, the message will not be shown to him. How can this be implemented?

Comment: So nothing at all should happen if the timer runs out while this specific fragment is not on screen?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes, the timer expires and nothing should happen if the user is not currently on the timer screen

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to do it, but this would be my approach.

1. When you start the timer, persist the end time (such as storing it in SharedPreferences).
2. When your fragment comes on screen, or when you start the timer, use this persisted time to determine if there is a future timer end time. If there is, start counting down with a CountDownTimer or coroutine, cancelling any previous timer that might have been set.
3. Cancel the timer whenever the fragment goes off screen.

I would typically persist the end time in a ViewModel, but to keep this example simple, I'll just do it in the Fragment.

```
private const TIMER_END_TIME_KEY = "timerEndTime"

class MyFragment: Fragment() {

    // ...

    private var countDownJob: Job? = null

    // Only safe while fragment attached
    private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
        get() = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(requireContext())

    private fun startNewCountDown(durationMillis: Long) {
        val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + durationMillis
        sharedPreferences.edit {
            putLong(TIMER_END_TIME_KEY, endTime)
        }
        prepareCountDownCallback()
    }

    private fun cancelCountDown() {
        countDownJob?.cancel()
        countDownJob = null
        sharedPreferences.edit {
            putLong(TIMER_END_TIME_KEY, 0L)
        }
    }

    private fun prepareCountDownCallback() {
        countDownJob?.cancel()
        val now = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val endTime = sharedPreferences.getLong(TIMER_END_TIME_KEY, 0L)
        countDownJob = if (endTime > now) {
            viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
                delay(endTime - now)
                // Show end of timer message
            }
        } else {
            null
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        countDownJob?.cancel()
        countDownJob = null
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        prepareCountDownCallback()
    }
}
```

Comment: One possible thing you’d want to add. What if the user leaves and immediately comes back a second later, such as what happens during a screen rotation, and the timer happens to run out during that momentary gap when the fragment is off-screen? To handle this, you might also want to persist the current time in `onPause()` and in `onResume` use that number as current time if it is less than ~3 seconds ago.